# Strange error: Inflate GZip String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, gzip

The line

```
test = Zlib::Inflate.inflate(inputstring)
```

Gives me NameError: uninitialized constant Tk::Button::Inflate

I'm using Tk for the interface, but if I uncomment this line everything works fine
(test isn't used elsewhere)

(Source for code below http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Zlib/Inflate.html )

```
def inflate(string)
zstream = Zlib::Inflate.new
buf = zstream.inflate(string)
zstream.finish
zstream.close
buf
end

newString = inflate(inputstring)
```

also gives me also a similar/same NameError

P.S. Edits are strange... (had to make more changes)

Comment: I did the edit, but you reverted the majority of it :-/

Comment: And you posted two times, you should change your username ;-)

Comment: Whoops, I'm new to stackoverflow sorry

Comment: I was just kidding, I hope you didn't mind :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you `require 'zlib'` at the beginning of your file?

Ruby is looking for the `Inflate` constant in the `Tk::Button` namespace, you can force it to look at the root with:

```
test = ::Zlib::Inflate.inflate(inputstring)
```